# rootViewDidChangeIntrinsicSize Not called

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I build a native ui component, and try to figure out on run time the `RCTRootView` size, so I set the `delegate` and I implemented `rootViewDidChangeIntrinsicSize:` function, but it have never been called.

So I look into the `react-native` implementation on when this `delegate` function should be called and I see this condition in this function `- (void)setIntrinsicSize:(CGSize)intrinsicSize`: (`RCTRootView.m` line #330)

```
// Don't notify the delegate if the content remains invisible or its size has not changed
if (bothSizesHaveAZeroDimension || sizesAreEqual) {
  return;
}
```

So I got in to this condition, and both sizes are 0 (and identical), and the `delegate` function isn't called.

But I see the view and its size is NOT 0.

Any help/ideas/lights?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the view I was adding as delegate was not being retained, so delegate was nil when the RCTRootView tried to call rootViewDidChangeIntrinsicSize

I fixed by adding this view as a variable from the viewController so it was retained

Not really sure is the same problem you had, but leaving this here so maybe helps someone